# Kohana not loading custom module class

Tags: php, module, kohana

I have created a module in Kohana but I have a problem when I try to use it. When I try to use the class I get the following error:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'PopcornInteractor' not found

APPPATH/classes/model/movie.php [ 120 ]
118     public function getPopcorn($popcorn) {
119         $uid = null;
120         $pci = new PopcornInteractor();
```

The `bootstrap.php` file has the following configuration for the modules

```
Kohana::modules(array(
  ...,
  'popcornmod' => MODPATH.'popcornmod'
));
```

When I debug the `Kohana::modules()` I get the following structure:

```
...
popcornmod : "\/var\/www\/html\/mywebsite.com\/modules\/popcornmod\/"
```

The structure of my files is:

```
modules                       
+                             
+-+popcornmod                 
   +                          
   +-+classes                 
   |  +                       
   |  +-+PopcornInteractor.php
   |                          
   +-+config                  
   |  +                       
   |  +-+popcornmod.php       
   |                          
   +-+init.php
```

The PopcornInteractor.php file has the following content:

```
class PopcornInteractor {
    protected $config;
    function __construct() {
        $this->config = Kohana::$config->load('popcornmod')->as_array();
    }
}
```

Finally, on the included files message that is shown when the error shows, it displays:

```
MODPATH/email/vendor/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php
MODPATH/email/vendor/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php
MODPATH/popcornmod/init.php
SYSPATH/classes/cookie.php
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/cookie.php
```

I try looking for PopcornInteractor.php but it is not in the included files.

The mod was working good in my local installation (OS X) but when I uploaded to the server (Linux) it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Changed the name of the file and now is working, the final structure is:

```
modules                       
+                             
+-+popcornmod                 
   +                          
   +-+classes                 
   |  +                       
   |  +-+popcorninteractor.php <-- change: lower cases
   |                          
   +-+config                  
   |  +                       
   |  +-+popcornmod.php       
   |                          
   +-+init.php
```